# portlet action url to change cotroll in java but don't need form

Tags: liferay

I was just beginning to learn liferay. My portlet have a Model search cotainer. This have a column (`<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="tenHoSo" herf="<%=detail%>"/>`)(i just know it when it have form in jsp) .i want to add portlet:actionURL(to change controll to java) when i click column tenHoSo. But i don't know how. Thank to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search shows a similar question :

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/40902770